# Why does .net mvc 4 web api service show local machine's path in exception message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

**The setup**

I have deployed a mvc 4 web api service to our web server, using the web deploy method in Visual Studio 2010.

**The problem**

When an exception is thrown, it lists my local machine on which the service was developed in the exception message.

**Example:**

... at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at ImageApp_REST_Services.Repositories.ImageLinkRepository.Get(String userId) in **C:\localuser\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ImageApp_REST_Services\ImageApp_REST_Services\Repositories\ImageLinkRepository.cs**:line 57\r\n

Does this mean the service is running on my local machine?

or

Is this just carried over from when I performed the web deploy?

In any event, how can I fix this so that the web server where the service is deployed is shown in the exception message and not my local development machine???

**Thanks!**

Comment: This info is saved in .pdb file where the project was built. It is provided for more detailed error messages I think. You can choose to not deploy pdb files to production server.

Comment: More info here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1212228.aspx/1

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Does this mean that if I choose to not deploy pdb files, what will the exceptions messages show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you deploy the application, you usually deploy PDB files with it. the PDB files contain debugger symbols that allow for line numbers to be indicated... They are generated at the time that you built/compiled the app for deployment/installation, so they reference your local path.

[PDB information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: How can I turn this off so that web deploy doesn't add these pdb files?  Or, are they typically included in production apps?

Comment: It has nothing to do with deployment, it's the build. You can go to the project's properties and under the Build tab click Advanced and then disable the PDB generation.

Answer (score 1):

It means you have deployed your code under a debug build or you have inadvertently deployed the PDB files with your deployment, either way the run-time has access to debug information that normally only the debugger would care about. The path information is relative to the machine the build was done on or where the PDB files were copied from.